# What is the logic behind Linux nice values?

Tags: linux, process, priority

Wouldn't it be nice if nice values in Linux were switched:
-20 = **low** priority
+20 = **high** priority

$ renice -p +5 # would get more CPU time and
$ renice -p -5 # less

Why was it selected to be inversed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)#Etymology):

> The name "niceness" originates from the idea that a process with a
>   higher niceness value is "nicer" to other processes in the system, as
>   it allows the other processes more CPU time.